# What is the order of seaonal differencing in ARIMAX with covariate explantory variables?

Tags: time-series, arima

In what order does ARIMAX perform which differentiations and apply exogeneous inputs? Seaonality in data can be removed through normal differencing (ARIMA), seasonal differencing (SARIMA), and/or using exogeneous inputs of covariates, fourier series, dummy variables. I am wondering in which order the arima algorithm does the differencing, and how to find out.

Say I have lights on/off coming on and off at same time every day and I look at energy use for lights and the data is called y(t).

My data is not stationary.

Therefore if the model is...

A: ARIMA[2,1,0] - won't be a very good model as one difference does does not remove the seasonality well
coefs AR1 and AR2.
First, takes the difference: `y_diff(t) = [y(t)-y(t-dt)]/dt`

Then `y_diff(t) = AR1 *y_diff(t-1) +AR2 *y_diff(t-2)`

B: ARIMA(2,1,0)24. seasonal arima
Does this transform my observation into a seasonally differenced  `y24(t) = y(t)-y(t-24)`
Then do the normal differencing? `y_diff_24(t) = [y24(t)-y24(t-dt)]/dt`
And then apply the coefficients?

`y_(t)= AR1 *y_diff(t-1) +AR2 *y_diff(t-2) +SAR1 *y_diff_24(t-1) +SAR2 *y_diff_24(t-2)`

C:  ARIMA(2,1,0)24. seasonal arima with an exogeneous input x(t)  of say same seasonal pattern (lag of 24 hours, but more nuanced)

`y_(t)= AR1 *y_diff(t-1) +AR2 *y_diff(t-2) +SAR1 *y_diff_24(t-1) +SAR2 *y_diff_24(t-2) +Coef(x(t)`

What order does this happen in? Is the exogenous applied first, and then the seasonal differencing? OR seasonal differencing first?

Have not been able to find a breakdown of these equations when all scenarios are together.

Thanks,
Mel